Upper bound for the absolute value of a derivative of a solution for the heat equation
This is the problem 7 in the chapter of parabolic equations in Fritz John's Book:
Let $f(x)$ be a continuous, bounded and positive function for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.
a) Prove that for $u$ given by:
\begin{equation}
    u(x,t) = \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{\frac{1}{2}}} \displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{\frac{-|x-y|^2}{4t}} f(y)dy
\end{equation}
We have that $|u(\xi +i\eta)| \leq e^{\frac{\eta^2}{4t}} u(\xi,t)$, for $t>0$.
Now, the one that got me stucked:
b) Show that $|u_x(x,t)| \leq \frac{e^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\sqrt{2t}} sup_{|y| \leq \sqrt{2t}} u(x+y,t)$, for $x,y$ real and $t>0$.
And he even gave us a tip: To use Cauchy's expression for $u_x$ as an integral of $u$ along a circle in the complex plane with center $x$ and radius $\sqrt{2t}$.
But to begin with, I don't see exactly what is the holomorphic function to write down the cauchy's formula.
